# ViewFlipper Compatibility

Tags: android, android-layout, compatibility

My app doesn't work in some versions and some advices.

For example:

- Samsung 4.04 - **Works**
- Motorola 4.04 - **Broken**
- Samsung 2.3.6 - **Works**
- LG 2.2.2 - **Broken**

If someone have a idea of what is happening, please tell me. I feel that must be something very simple.

My manifest is declaring min sdk=4 and max=16.

I use a ViewFlipper to change layouts, maybe that's the problem. The app only closes when it reaches this part.

Sorry for not having the crash logs.

```
public class ImagesActivity extends Activity {

private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private ShakeEventListener mSensorListener;
private ViewFlipper mFlipper;
private Animation Animation, Animation2, Animation3, Animation4;
private Random randomGenerator = new Random();

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.imagesview);

    final LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.images_view);

    //declaração ViewFlipper das telas
    mFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.mFlipper1);

     //declaração das var para o evento Shake
     mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
     mSensorListener = new ShakeEventListener(); 

     //declaração anim 1 - Slide from left
     Animation = (Animation) AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slideleft);
     Animation.setFillAfter(true);

     //declaração anim 2 - Slide from right
     Animation2 = (Animation) AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slideright);
     Animation.setFillAfter(true);

     //declaração anim 3 - Slide from down
     Animation3 = (Animation) AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slideup);
     Animation.setFillAfter(true);

     //declaração anim 4 - Slide from up
     Animation4 = (Animation) AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slidedown);
     Animation.setFillAfter(true);

     //Event Shake para execução das telas random
     mSensorListener.setOnShakeListener(new ShakeEventListener.OnShakeListener() {
          public void onShake() {
              int random;
              Random RandomView = new Random();
                 int nextViewIndex = RandomView.nextInt(18);
                 while (nextViewIndex == mFlipper.getDisplayedChild()) {
                     nextViewIndex = RandomView.nextInt(18);
                 }
                random = randomGenerator.nextInt(4);

                if(random ==1)
                    myLayout.startAnimation(Animation);
                else if(random ==2)
                    myLayout.startAnimation(Animation2);
                else if(random ==3)
                    myLayout.startAnimation(Animation3);
                else
                    myLayout.startAnimation(Animation4);

                 mFlipper.setDisplayedChild(nextViewIndex);
          }
          });
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(mSensorListener,
        mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
        SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mSensorListener);
    super.onStop();
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is broken about it? what happens when it crashes? more information needed

Comment: the error happend on other phone, so i dont have any log that do a better explanation about it. The only thing that happens is that the app forces close when reach this activity. I have other 2 activity before this one, one of them finishes, the other is a main screen which leads to that one.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this

```
private Animation Animation, Animation2, Animation3, Animation4;
```

use better names, and are you sure that you have 18 different views?

You also need to set the animation on your ViewFlipper, not the layout

Comment: Thanks. Yes, i have 18 views. But yeah, i'll try to call on the viewflipper instead of the layout. And do the animation's name is that relevant to force the app to close? @ElefantPhace

Comment: I changed the animation names, actually, now i called the animation only when it reachs the part of the first random number. So i don't declare the animation until that part. And also changed the animation to the flipper. But it still not working on those versions and devices. @ElefantPhace

Comment: you're going to need to get your hands on those devices and test it yourself so you can debug what's going wrong